# MVC Website Cant Connect to Database on Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure

This is my first MVC Website with a database hosted on Azure.

I have deployed the database and the website. However I get an Access Denied error message:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)]

What I don't get is that I can run the app via Visual Studio connected via the Azure connection string locally without any problems. I can speak to the db remotely but not within Azure!!!

Here's the connection string I'm using:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnString"
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;
    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
    provider connection string=&quot;
    Data Source = tcp:mybdurl.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=myDb;
    persist security info=True;
    User ID=MyId;
    Password=MyPassword;
    MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
    application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" 
    />
</connectionStrings>
```

I'm guessing there is a missing magic Azure element that allows access. Both are in the same data centre and within the same account.

Cheers

Comment: In Azure Portal > Databases > Configure have you got 'Windows Azure Services' Allowed?

Comment: that is weird. Maybe your Azure portal connections strings are wrong but your web.config strings are right (watch issues with &amp; and &quot;) ? That could cause this issue

Comment: I got rid of the &quot;'s from the string and open the IP range to 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 which made no difference! I can still access the db from my local machine but not via Azure!!! Thanks for the &quot; suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I was publishing the web.config file individually in Visual Studio, not realising it wasn't actually updating on Azure. I went back to old fashioned FTP and indeed the live web.config was still the original not the one for Azure.

Manually uploaded it and it worked!

What didn't it publish???